# What means an "E" or "e" character on larger fractional and float outputs?

Tags: java, floating-point

Studying java, I have had an unexpected output for the following code:

```
int i = 1234567890;
float f = i;
int result = i - (int)f;
```

It's turned back as the value for the "result" variable the value -46, and I was expecting 0.0, believing that "float f = i" would be converted to 1234567890.0 instead of 1.23456794E9.
Trying to understand it, I have noted that for the float type is only permitted, at most, 7 digits before the radix point, and, if is imputed a float with more that 7 digits before the radix point, compilers output a string that is composed with the radix point at the 2nd index place of that string and, at the penultimate index place,  its returns a "E" or "e".
What is it? What "e" means?

Comment: ["*for any two real numbers a and b, the usage of "aEb" would indicate a value of a × 10**b"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), in E notation. The `E` stands for *exponent*.

`1.23456794E9` means 1.23456794 × 10<sup>9</sup> which is the same as 1234567940.

The limited precision of the `float` type means that the value is not the exact same value as the `int`. The scientific notation is used to show large or small values, it doesn't have anything to do with the loss of precision.

Comment: **E** stand for "exponent," and the notation came into life on hand-held calculators.

Comment: **e** is also used, but it's less encouraged since it reminds the famous constant "e".