# Compare double values

Tags: java, double

Here is code:

```java
 double d1 = 2.4066419461049408E7;
 double d2 = 500.0;
 int retval = Double.compare(d1, d2);
    
 if(retval > 0) {
     System.out.println("d1 is greater than d2");
 } else if(retval < 0) {
     System.out.println("d1 is less than d2");
 } else {
     System.out.println("d1 is equal to d2");
 }
```

Output:

```
d1 is greater than d2
```

Why? How to get right answer?

Comment: Related: [What means an “E” or “e” character on larger fractional and float outputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649756/what-means-an-e-or-e-character-on-larger-fractional-and-float-outputs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the right answer: `2.4066419461049408E7` is (by far) greater than `500.0`

**Notice the `E7` at the end** of the 1st number: this means `x10^7` (exponent).

You are thus comparing `24066419.461049408` to `500.0`.

Comment: It’s not only the correct answer, it is also well explained (+1).

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot.